# Width ignored on flexbox items

Tags: css, width, flexbox

http://jsfiddle.net/XW9Se/

I've set `width: 200px;` on the left `<div>` but if I view it with the browser inspector tool it appears that the real width is random or something. It keeps changing depending on the window size.

Why doesn't the width take effect?

**EDIT**: If I remove `width: 100%` the width stays fixed. But I need that so the `#main` div takes the remaining width :( Is there any way to have the sidebar @ fixed width and the other `<div>` fill the rest of the container width? `width: auto;` on `#main` doesn't work..

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of a flexbox that it changes on window resizing?

Comment: yes, but I only want 1 flex column to change width :P

Comment: try adding `flex-flow: wrap;` to the container

Comment: fyi: flex-shrink defaults to 1

Comment: use this style: `#main{ flex: 1; }` to take the remaining width according to the other element's fixed width.

Comment: I'd love to see an answer that includes an explanation of what's happening and how the solution helps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove the width on `.container > div` and use [`flex: auto;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-initial) on `#main`: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XW9Se/1/)

```
#main {
   flex: auto; 
   background: lightblue; 
  -webkit-order: 2;
   order: 2;     
}
```

Answer (score 268):

The answer from Adrift is perfect; but a change to make it more **flex** would be

```
#left{
    flex-basis: 200px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

And remove the width property entirely.

It would be the **flex** way to say that the element will have an invariable width of 200px

Comment: shorthand: `flex: 0 0 200px;`

Comment: Simply add  `flex-shrink: 0` property and  css width will be respected.

Comment: This combined with `order: 2` (to switch it to the right) worked flawlessly to do a side panel. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to add in that I only needed `flex-shrink: 0` to fix my personal issue (where `flex: auto` alone didn't fix it)

Comment: Then why when I change the direction of the flex container, the flex-grow: 0; not working? The shape is out of shape. Can you tell me why :/ ?

Comment: Just a note for anyone copy pasting, these grow and shrink have to be applied to the FLEX CHILD and not the container.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. For my case, it worked without providing flex-basis. Just to keep in mind in case someone is still having problems.

Comment: @hayley If the flex direction is column, you set a fixed width and this answer affects height.

Comment: @AshishRawat that's not good, if you just specify `flex-shrink:0` without the flex-basis and only width, your other flex sibling may overflow your container (which can be a big problem with flex-direction row)

Answer (score 101):

My preferred way of dealing with this situation is to add:

```
flex-shrink: 0;
```

This way you may continue using `width` in your Flex container and you've given it specific information about how you wish this flex item to behave.

Another option, depending on the requirement is to use `min-width`, which is respected when using flex.

Answer (score 19):

Give the `#left` div a `min-width` of `200px`, should do the job.

Comment: pretty much the simplest answer.

Answer (score 3):

add `display: contents` on the element or div you want to maintain the width.

Answer (score 2):

*Also (if nothing from above works)*

Check your **min-width** and **max-width**.
It fixed the same problem for me by increasing their range.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with a flex not respecting min-width when there was not enough content to fill that width.

Added the CSS rule `box-sizing: initial;` on the same flex element that had the non-working min-width declaration.

Answer (score -3):

Add `display:inline-block;` in left class

Comment: The OP is using flex though :)