# Why flex items width grow with flex-grow: 0

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The last question I met is the same as the link here: [Width ignored on flexbox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406397/width-ignored-on-flexbox-items)
Everything looks so nice but at the last moment, I want to change the direction of the flex container, so I added `flex-direction: column;` then the flex items grow as wide as the container, but I do have `flex-grow: 0;` Can anyone explain why the result will go like that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`flex-grow` is the ability of the  flex items in the direction given by `flex-direction`.

What you are searching for is [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)